# Finding out which line is moved in C#

Tags: c#

I am working on program in which I have two bitmap lines in a panel. Both lines can move and rotate and move in panel using mouse. 
Now I want to find out which line is moved or rotated but I don't know how to do that, here is code:

```
public void LineMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var l = (Line)sender;
    //here is rotate and move code.

   // Now after that I want code like this
    If (l == line1)
        //msg(It is line1)
    else
        //msg(It is line2)
}
```

So please provide any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: On rotating line does this event trigger?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you have to do the following steps

Assign name to both lines let say "Line1" and "Line2" respectively

Then in your code do the following

```
 if(l.Name.equals("Line1")){
       //Line1
   }

 else if(l.Name.equals("Line2")){
   //Line2
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, please can you tell me how to give name to the lines.

Comment: make sure to add other properties your are adding

Answer (score 1):

Is you are you are using [System.Windows.Shapes.Line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line(v=vs.110).aspx), you can use its `Line.Name` property to determine which `Line` is the `sender`:

```
if (l.Name == "line1")
    //msg(It is line1)
else
    //msg(It is line2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tried that but its not working. Name is showing empty.

Comment: @DhvanitAkbari how do you create your `Line` in the first place? In the `Line` creation. gives name: `line1.Name = "line1";` then you can later recall the `Line` by name.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that you have given [Name for Line 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name(v=vs.110).aspx) and Line 2, Let `"line1"` be the name for Line 1 Then Change the condition like this:

```
var l = (Line)sender;
If (l.Name == "line1")
    //msg(It is line1)
else
    //msg(It is line2)
```

You can give the name for Line using :

```
 <Line  Name="Line1" ></Line>
```

If you are Creating it from Codebehind you can use like this:

```
Line line1 = new Line();
line1.Name = "Line1";
```

Comment: Thank you, please can you tell me how to give name to the lines.